# Figurative use of "buy" in a phrase such as "just to buy myself peace of mind"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

I came across the phrase "just to buy myself peace of mind". I am wondering, are there other examples where "buy" is used similarly to communicate paying a figurative price in order to have something?

What can I use to fill in the blank here?

> I did X just to buy myself _________

Comment: You can talk about 'buying time' - doing something to postpone a deadline.

Comment: Parents who are neighbours will swap evenings to watch the kids to buy themselves some peace and quiet. A hockey player might fake a pass to buy himself some room to shoot.